# Setting className string dynamically Javascript \ React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, web, sass

In my current project, I'm setting up mobile support the following way:

1) I'm creating all the relevant components both for desktop and mobile. On most of my pages, they're the same.

2) I'm creating two .scss files, one for desktop and one for mobile (determined by a media query covering the entire file)

3) I'm then attaching both styles in the className of my components, and then only the relevant file gets set. It looks like this:

```
// Styles
import styles from '../../components/Timeline/timeline.scss';
import mobileStyles from '../../components/Timeline/mobileTimeline.scss';

// Example component
<Row className={`${styles.container} ${mobileStyles.container}`}>
   <div className={`${styles.myComponent} ${mobileStyles.myComponent}`}/>
</Row>
```

It works great, but in order to make the code a bit cleaner, I decided to write a helper function to generate the entire string for the className ->

```
const setStyle = styleName => `${styles.styleName} ${mobileStyles.styleName}`
```

However, setStyle always returns 'unidentified' (*the function is defined after the styles imports of-course)

I think I understand why it happens, but I wonder, is there a way we could dynamically access style object properties like that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a property from an object given the key name in a variable, use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors):

```
const setStyle = styleName => `${styles[styleName]} ${mobileStyles[styleName]}`
```

This assumes that `styles` and `mobileStyles` are available in the scope of the function, otherwise you would also need to pass them:

```
const setStyle = (styleName, styles, mobileStyles) => `${styles[styleName]} ${mobileStyles[styleName]}`
```